# Parse ISO 8601 microseconds in Typescript

Tags: typescript, parsing, time

I need to parse timestamp in `ISO 8601` with microseconds. I do not want to lose the precision. I require the parsing in order to be able to add filtering to queries.

A database that supports microseconds creates these timestamps, so I do not have to worry about creating these in an environment that does not have enough precision. But the database can change, so I want to have a generic parser that can handle with or without microseconds timestamps.
If I use `Date` I lose the microsecond precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created my own class `PrecisionDate` that stores a number with milliseconds just as Date but with the fractional part for microseconds. It parses the timestamp using `new Date()` to millisecond precision. Afterward, I use a regex and a capture group to get the microseconds.

```
const ISO8601_REGEX = /^(\d{4})-(0\d|1[0-2])-([0-2]\d|3[0-1])T([01]\d|2[0-4]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)[.,](\d{3})?(\d{3})?(\d+)?\+(\d\d):(\d\d)/;

public static parse(timestamp: string): number {
    // Get the full time except for the microseconds
    let time = Date.parse(timestamp);

    const captureGroups = ISO8601_REGEX.exec(timestamp);
    const microSeconds = captureGroups[ISO8601_REGEX_MICRO];

    if (microSeconds) {
        time += parseInt(microSeconds, 10) / 1000;
    }

    return time;
}
```